# Get/Set Notes in Custom PowerPoint Add-In

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I have looked through all the example PowerPoint add-ins and have not found a sample of this.

How can I get the notes for a given slide (not necessarily the current slide) or update the notes in my PowerPoint add-in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid interacting with Slide Notes isn't supported. I suggest adding a request to the [Office Dev UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for this.

Answer (score -1):

Update:
below answer only applied to VBA.

---

to Read:

```
sNotes = oSlide.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.text
```

and the write/update it'll be the same.

Comment: That works for VBA but OP tagged the question with Office-JS, not VBA.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Yes you are right. Thanks for the headup.